# Send SMS through AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms

I am trying to send SMS using node.js and through AWS. I am getting the error below

```
originalError: 
 { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
   at errnoException (dns.js:53:10)
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:95:26)
 message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443',
 code: 'NetworkingError',
 errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
 syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
 hostname: 'sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
 host: 'sns.southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
 port: 443,
 region: 'southeast-2',
 retryable: true,
 time: 2018-08-31T12:35:52.241Z },
```

time: 2018-08-31T12:35:52.241Z }

My code is below...

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'AKIAIUZOX3xxxxxxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxj2t1y22qxxxxxxxxxx2vf6KyFiV7Txxxx',
    region: 'southeast-2'
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:82688246XXXX:xxx';
var to_number = '917980981798';

sns.subscribe({
    Protocol: 'sms',
    TopicArn: SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
    Endpoint: to_number,
    Topicowner: '826882469571',
    endpoint  : '+917980981798'
}, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error when subscribe", error);
    }

    var params = {
        TargetArn: SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message: 'test message',
        //hardcode now
        Subject: 'Admin'
    };

    sns.publish(params, function(err_publish, data) {
        if (err_publish) {
            console.log('Error sending a message', err_publish);

        } else {
            console.log('Sent message:', data.MessageId);
        }
    });
});
```

I am not receiving the SMS. Where should I change? Shall I have to change in AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

Your region is incorrect, it should be `ap-southeast-2` not `south-east-2`

Comment: yes, I added the region, now it says message ID, but I am not receiving SMS

Answer (score 0):

You can test the sending of an SMS with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws sns publish --phone-number (In +Intl format) --message Foo
```

This will check whether SMS is working with your phone number and whether your AWS credentials have the necessary permissions to send an SMS via Amazon SNS.